# Cannot align widgets in window, Python gridview

Tags: python, gridview

As per tutorial in youtube and certain web sites, I came to know that grid layout works like xlsheet on the basis of rows and columns. But I am stuck on a simple design.[image]

But my design becomes like this. I am totally noob to python. 
Please help me. Why is my design going wrong?

This is my output.
[image]

and my code is:

```
 # ----- Row 0 -----
lbl_head = tk.Label(win,text ='Titile',font = ('courier'))
lbl_head.grid (row=0, column=5, padx = 120, pady = 10,columnspan=2)

lbl_Amount = tk.Label(win,text ='Amount$:',font = ('courier'))
lbl_Amount.grid (row=2, column=0)

label_TotalAmount = tk.Label(win,text ='11111',font = ('courier'))
label_TotalAmount.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

lbl_Balance = tk.Label(win,text ='Balance$:',font = ('courier'))
lbl_Balance.grid (row=2, column=2)

label_totalBalance = tk.Label(win,text ='11111',font = ('courier'))
label_totalBalance.grid(row = 2, column = 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your very close Jenny. It's great you drew it out too.

Firstly if you use grid but I suggest you dont use `padx` and `pady`. That's probably why your "Title" is off. Secondly it's better to imagine your design like like a spreadsheet too.

Where the rows and columns you put into the grid function correspond to this grid on your design.

[image]

Here's my solution to your design however, tweak to your needs.

```
lbl_head = tk.Label(win,text ='Title',font = ('courier'))
lbl_head.grid (row=0, column=1)

lbl_Amount = tk.Label(win,text ='Amount$:',font = ('courier'))
lbl_Amount.grid (row=1, column=0)

label_TotalAmount = tk.Label(win,text ='11111',font = ('courier'))
label_TotalAmount.grid(row = 1, column=1)

lbl_Balance = tk.Label(win,text ='Balance$:',font = ('courier'))
lbl_Balance.grid (row=1, column=2)

label_totalBalance = tk.Label(win,text ='11111',font = ('courier'))
label_totalBalance.grid(row = 1, column = 3)

button1 = tk.Button(win, text="Button1", fg="red")
button1.grid(row = 1, column = 4)

label_Input = tk.Label(win,text ='Input',font = ('courier'))
label_Input.grid(row =2, column=0)

entry_Entry = tk.Entry(win, font = ('courier'))
entry_Entry.grid(row=2, column=1)

button2 = tk.Button(win, text="Button2", fg="red")
button2.grid(row = 2, column = 2)

button3 = tk.Button(win, text="Button3", fg="red")
button3.grid(row = 2, column = 3)
```

A good guide you can go through is [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-index.htm).

Comment: Thanks so much for this. Can i know how the button1 occupy the space of row1 and row 3?

Comment: Do you mean column 3? See the line `button1.grid(row = 1, column = 4)`, just play around with the column number. Also could you mark this question as solved?